# what are the uses of this identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Consider this wonderful ( think it is) identity 
$$\begin{align*}
&a+b(1+a) + c(1+a)(1+b) + d(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)
+\cdots+l(1+a)(1+b)\cdots(1+k)\\ 
&\qquad= 
 (1+a)(1+b)(1+c)\cdots(1+l)-1
\end{align*}
$$

I believe there must be some beautiful applications, for example deriving some other identities, of it. Can someone please explore these possibilities?

Comment: When $a = b = \dotsb = 1$, it becomes $\sum_{0}^{n-1} 2^{i} = 2^n - 1$. Similar geometric sums can be derived by setting $a, b, \dotsc$ equal.

Comment: Somewhere between "not constructive" and "not a real question." I wish one could vote to close as "fishing expedition," which is what I think this question is, and which is not really what this site is meant to handle.

Answer (score 9):

There is a whole article devoted to applications of this identity: Bhatnagar, [*In Praise of an Elementary Identity of Euler*](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_18/Abstracts/v18i2p13.html).